# Check if folder have a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to make a comparison between two folders to validate if it have something missing and I am stuck.

```
import os
ParaBase = listdir(path=caminho)
ParaChecar = listdir(path=caminho2)
Falta = []

def Compara(ParaBase,ParaChecar):
    try:
        Range = len(ParaBase)
        for item in ParaBase:
            if item == ParaChecar:
                return True
            elif item == ParaBase[Range-1]:
                return False
    except WindowsError:
        print('Falha')

for item in ParaChecar:
    if Compara(ParaBase,item) == True:
        print(item)
```

The idea was to get 2 folders and see if all the files are ok, with a folder being like a base untouched, a perfect situation and the other a folder who's the users can do whatever they want, than I could send the files who's missing to the folder again and fix any missing files.

It work's to find the one's who are equal (what a miracle) but I stuck on how to see if something is not found x.x I'm using python 3.8

Comment: If you convert the file lists to sets you can do set operations like e. g. difference.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
"I stuck" is not a problem specification.

Comment: See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Comment: @Prune , that's a good advice, I wasn't asking questions putting the outputs of my code's, this can be helpful. I was stuck on the comparission, my code was giving me the same result with the same files about 8 times before I could find what's different x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Michael Butscher suggested, convert the listdirs to set will ease the implementation:

was set random values to `dir1` and `dir2`

```
dir1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
set_dir1 = set(dir1)
dir2 = ["2", "3", "4"]
set_dir2 = set(dir2)

intersected = set_dir1.intersection(set_dir2)
only_in_1 = set_dir1 - intersected
only_in_2 = set_dir2 - intersected

print("only in 1: " + str(only_in_1))
print("only in 2: " + str(only_in_2))
```

output:

```
only in 1: {'1'}
only in 2: {'4'}
```

used `intersection` to find the matches betweens the elements in 2 dirs, then subtract the intersected from the listdir elements to find the unique values per each dir.

convert to `set` is acceptable solution, because as far as I know, it's illegal to create 2 different files or directories holding the same name.

Comment: Thanks, this make SUPER easy to solve, I confess, I'll try to read more about set command cause is too much useful.